# Constructing a boost::posix_time::time_duration from microseconds

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

One can get the total number of microseconds from a time_duration via the total_microseconds method, but I can't figure out how to re-construct a time_duration from that number. There seems to be no constructors for such a purpose in the documentation, am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

There are [boost::posix_time::microseconds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#time_duration_count_constr):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
namespace bpt = boost::posix_time;
int main()
{
    bpt::time_duration td = bpt::microseconds(12345678);
    std::cout << td << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...I tried that. I feed in the number "34200186270", which by my calculations should be about 9:30, however, when I print the resulting duration it gives 00:35:47.483647.

Comment: Edit: wait on that one, I'm getting the right number when I feed it into your test program, must be a code error somewhere. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Craig I get `09:30:00.186270`. Your duration is 2^31 microseconds, perhaps you stored it in a 32-bit signed number somewhere?

Comment: It seems I'm having trouble turning "34200186270" into an int, atoi returns nonsense and lexical_cast throws...